# Google Tag Manager events stopped working suddenly

Tags: google-analytics, salesforce, google-tag-manager

I've been supporting on activities related to the configuration and creation of events with Google Tag Manager on a site created using SalesForce.

We've put this in production almost two months ago, and everything looked to be working fine.
But from 1 month ago (to be exact on June 10th), events stopped working properly suddenly. Nothing have been change by our side at the GTM configuration.

I double checked the events and everything looks fine. Also, I've checked at the output console of the portal, and I noticed they're a lot of errors related to a Policy Security Violation.

**Refused to connect to '[URL]' because it violates the following Content Security...**

Do you think this errors could be affecting the flow of the other scripts, and by consequence affecting our GTM events from beign triggered? Or what could be another potential cause to this issue?

Thank you everyone.

Comment: I assume it is listing additional information. Are there any URLs listed that are GTM/GA related? Is this showing for everyone in the console or just you?

Comment: I assume these URLs are indirectly related to GTM/GA. Our marketing team recently added a Linkedin Insight feature. So probably could be related. Also, today I've tried to add those URLs causing the error into a whitelist but not getting the rtesult we were expecting (GTM events triggering properly)

Comment: Also, today I've realized that our GTM tag is declared with a <x-oasis-script> (the once suggested to be used with SalesForce sites). But the standard instalation of GTM it is suggested with a normal <script>. So, also probably this could be causing a conflict.